# Pyspark: Flag for product already purchased before

Tags: python, pyspark, feature-engineering

I am facing a dilemma in my code. Any help is appreciated.

I am trying to create a new column using PySpark where I would flag, at each transaction, if a product had been bought in a previous transaction

My data currently looks like this:

[image]

However, I would want to add a flag column, but also another column specifying at which visit this was already purchased. In nature, this doesn't sound difficult, but for some reason I cannot find any efficient way to build this. Thanks

Ideally, the result would look like the following:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use *window* functions to achieve your requirement.

the program would be as follows :

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView('df')

df_output = spark.sql(""" select ID, DATE, PRODUCT, VISIT, case when in_visit is null then 0 else 1 end as REPEAT, IN_VISIT  from (select *, lead(visit,1) over (partition by ID, PRODUCT order by visit desc) as in_visit from df )""")

display(df_output)
```

the output dataframe is as follows

```
# +-----+--------+--------------+-----+------+--------+
# |   ID|    DATE|       PRODUCT|VISIT|REPEAT|IN_VISIT|
# +-----+--------+--------------+-----+------+--------+
# |83728|12/21/17|Hand Sanitizer|    1|     0|    null|
# |83728|  1/1/19|    Shampoo AB|    3|     1|       2|
# |83728|  4/3/18|    Shampoo AB|    2|     0|    null|
# |83728|  4/3/18|     Soft Soap|    2|     0|    null|
# +-----+--------+--------------+-----+------+--------+
```